# Accessing parent from UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

I have a UIView (it's actually a PM::Screen) and am adding a subView which is a UICollectionViewController's view. I'm using this technique to switch between things like grid/list ala the Instagram profile screen.

Selecting a cell should open a new screen, which I want to push on to the parent view's (the PM::Screen) navigation controller.

My question is how do I get the collectionView(view, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: index_path) to call a method on the parent PM screen?

Will I have to use NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but... are you trying to push from the selected cell itself? That seems dangerous due to cell reuse -- might be tricky to ensure a cell doesn't have a stale reference to the containing view.

Comment: I'm passing data from the selected cell to a method in the parent, which then does the pushing

Comment: So, can't the collectionView just have a reference to the parent ViewController and use it to push? I.e. Call partentViewController.navigationController.pushViewController(...)

Comment: parentViewController gave me errors, is there anything wrong with the way I'm doing it now?

Comment: Use protocols for passing data to parent

Comment: @AnnaDickinson or are you saying I should specify what `parentViewController` is?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes -- I didn't realize "parentViewController" was an existing property, and I don't know if it's set to the correct thing automatically. I meant -- in general -- give the collectionView a reference to its parent when you create it.  And as @AdeelUrRehman mentions, it might be better to define a delegate protocol which allows the collectionView to notify its parent when the push needs to happen rather than doing the push itself -- that's the usual design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed with:

```
self.view.superview.nextResponder.theMethodToCall
```

Is there a better way?

**UPDATE:**

I ended up passing a reference to the parent to the child, and using that reference to call the method on the parent

Comment: Make sure it was a weak reference or you'll get a retain cycle!